# Need Page 1 webform to pass variables into the src portion of an iframe located in Page 2

Tags: php, variables

Noob looking for some help. I am a slow learner.

I have a small form on my front page which asks "arrival date" and "departure date."  I need to capture the results of those two questions and pass it into the src portion of an iframe located on the page which appears when "submit" is pressed.

The src is NOT on the same server.  It looks something like:
www.bob.com/res.php3?day_a=VAR1&month_a=VAR2&day_d=VAR3&month_d=VAR4&

If you can help me I would appreciate all that you can offer, I am starting from scratch here.

The code on page 1 is borrowed and looks something like this:

```
    <script language="javascript">
function changeIFrame() {
   window.open('http://www.bob.com/res3.php');
   }
/***********************************************
* Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
* This notice MUST stay intact for use
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
***********************************************/

var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<20; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}
</script>

<form action="" name="someform">
<select id="day_a">
</select> 
<select id="month_a">
</select> 
<select id="year_a">
</select> 
<input type="button" onclick="changeIFrame();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload=function(){
populatedropdown("day_a", "month_a", "year_a")
}
</script>
```

I tried using bob-the-destroyer's code in page 2 to grab these values but had no luck.

Comment: iframes are dated tech, you should be using ajax.

Comment: i agree dagon, but the src of the iframe is not on our server and we have zero ability to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the src attribute of the iframe is like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeIFrame() {
   var day_a = document.getElementById("day_a").value;
   var month_a = document.getElementById("month_a").value;
   var newSrc = "www.bob.com/res.php?day_a=" + day_a + "&month_a=" + month_a;
   document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = newSrc;
}
</script>

<input id="day_a" type="text" />
<input id="month_a" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="changeIFrame();" />

<iframe id="my_iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Alright, I am getting there.  I don't know if it was clear from my description but the iframe is located on a second page, which is meant to load when the button is clicked.

Comment: So you want to submit data from page A to page B. And page B has the iframe on it?

Answer (score 0):

Taking from your comment from Spidy's answer, "the iframe is located on a second page, which is meant to load when the button is clicked.", it's *conceptually* just like the javascript way, except working with `posted` values made available to the server and a first-time page build...

```
<?php

// get UNIX TIMESTAMPS of client's posted form fields
$arrivalDate = strtotime(trim($_POST['arrivalDate']));
$departureDate = strtotime(trim($_POST['departureDate']));
if (!$arrivalDate OR !$departureDate)
    // you will need better validation and error handling than this though
    die("These aren't valid dates."); 

// parse month/day numeric values
$day_a = date('n', $arrivalDate);
$month_a = date('j', $arrivalDate);
$day_d = date('n', $departureDate);
$month_d = date('j', $departureDate);

// here echo HTML or escape out of PHP to begin building your page


// draw iframe using parsed values
echo "<iframe src=\"www.bob.com/res.php3?day_a=" . $day_a . "&month_a=" 
    . $month_a . "&day_d=" . $day_d . "&month_d=" . $month_d . "\"></iframe>";


// here echo more HTML or escape out of PHP to finish building your page

?>
```

Note on that last echo: it's sloppy and you could better disregard all that concatenation , but I segmented it just to better show where PHP variables should be placed.

Comment: Bob-the-destroyer thanks for your help.  I am still trying to get this to work.  Largely I am struggling with what goes on page 1 and what goes on page 2.  I borrowed the code below.  For the sake of simplicity, I am temporarily skirting around validation and timestamps.  This of course goes on page 1, but using your code on page 2 (modified) it does not work.

Comment: @Michael: my code above is meant for Page 2.  The `$_POST` values "arrivalDate" and "departureDate" should come from input boxes by those names on the form on Page 1, which the client fills out and submits.  Keep in mind, because iframes are frequently used for malicious reasons, there's a good chance the client's browser may actually block by default all interactivity with this iframe.  Even if their browser didn't block that element, there would be very little interactivity permitted by standards between what's in the iframe and your own site.